# StructureMap injection per web request

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, structuremap

I have an ASP.NET Web Api 2 REST service with several controllers. Each one of these controllers' constructor has got an ILogger argument which I have to inject with StructureMap. Is it possibile to instantiate an ILogger per request, in order to get client's specific informations - such as the IP address - and thus save the log file to a specific path?

This is the code I'm trying to run in the DefaultRegistry, but HttpContext is always null. Where am I wrong?

```
For<ILogger>()
    .Use(() => new TextFileLogger(
        HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress +
        DirectorySeparatorChar + "log.txt"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on StructureMap but I understand the problem. The problem you have is that you use runtime data to build up your object graph. And [injecting runtime data is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

The simple solution here is not to use the `HttpContext` directly in your composition root but to create a provider which you can use to determine the path in the `FileLogger`. In that case both the `FileLogger` as this new provider can become singleton, which is far easier to work with and understand.

A provider could be as simple as (c#6 syntax):

```
public class HttpLogfileProvider : ILogFileProvider
{
     public string PathToLogfile => 
        Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress, "log.txt");
}
```

Your `FileLogger` can use this provider as follows:

```
public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly ILogFileProvider logFileProvider;
    public FileLogger(ILogFileProvider logFileProvider)
    {
        this.logFileProvider = logFileProvider;
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
         using (var writer = new StreamWriter(this.currentLogFile))
         {
              writer.WriteLine(message);
         }
    }

    private string currentLogFile =>
         this.logFileProvider.PathToLogFile;
}
```

I'm not an structuremap user but I think the registration should be:

```
For<ILogFileProvider>.Use<HttpLogfileProvider>.Singleton;
For<ILogger>.Use<FileLogger>.Singleton;
```

Comment: Really thank you, man. I'm new to dependency injection and these infos are pure gold to me!